# how to get music waveform data in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, audiowaveform

I searched several data.

Among them, `Wavesurfer.js` was ideal, but it seems that it is impossible to use in Nestjs.

I also want to get 1000(ex.) Number arrays, whether it's a one -second music or a 100 -second music.

And I used a keyword called `numOfSample` in `waveform-node`, but I couldn't use it properly.

If not, I wonder if there is a way to get the average value by setting the number of sampling in the `audiowaveform` command.